# pass different @Configuration bean to a rest based Client

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, autowired, resttemplate

I have two different configuration which i would be loading from application yml. The properties are same but the values might differ.

How do i make this work **giveMeRestTemplate(Type config)**

// app.yml

```
    bus:
      tyres:8
      seats:40
      color:red
      url: www.businfo.com
    car:
      tyres:4
      seats:6
      color:blue
      url: www.carinfo.com
```

So i have different ConfigruationProperties class for this like below one other as CarConfig

```
@ConfigurationProperties("bus")
    public class BusConfig{
      public int tyres;
      public int seats;
      public string color ;
      public string url;
    //setters and getters below.

    }
```

Then i have a rest client which i use to invoke some api to fetch information. So this api can return information of different types of vehicles you can say.

```
public class RestClientHelper{

    public RestTemplate giveMeRestTemplate(Type config);
    {
     return restTemplate; //using the above type which might have url to the specific api to call.

     }
}
```

The idea is that the calling code can get different rest templates based on what config was sent to it.

```
   public SomeClient{

    @Autowired
    RestClientHelper rch;
    
    @Autowired
    BusConfig bc;

    @Autowired
    CarConfig cc;

    
    public void publishDetails(){
     rch.giveMeRestTemplate(bc);    //so if i send cc then it should prepare rest template for cc
    }
   }
```

Comment: What is your question / issue / problem ?

Comment: giveMeRestTemplate(Type type) how do i make this work

Comment: anyone else can help to make this generic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever posted by @Archie(Thanks) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63117456/3560140) gave me insight to write it like this.

```
public enum Type {
    BUS, CAR
}
```

So storing the string as key in map,which tell me to which specific type this config is.

```
   @ConfigurationProperties("rest-config")
    public class RestConfig {
        private Map<String, ConfigType> type = new HashMap<>();
        public static class ConfigType {
            private int tyres;
            private int seats;
            private string color;
            private string url;
        }
    }
```

So helper can take a type actual config type(this is where my caller code can send it a type based on which template can be created rather than reading inside this method about which type of config it is.)

```
    public class RestClientHelper{
    
        public RestTemplate giveMeRestTemplate(RestConfig.type config);
        {
         return restTemplate; //using the above type which might have url to the specific api to call.
    
         }
    }
```

Client Code

```
public SomeClient{

    @Autowired
    RestClientHelper rch;
    
    public void publishDetails(){
     rch.giveMeRestTemplate(rch.type.get(Type.BUS.toString()));    //I am sending a actual type by using enum to match the string name
    }
   }
```

Comment: This question just popped up in my notification after my answer was upvoted. It's funny how the accepted solution is exactly mine with a twist of serializing `Type` enum to string; all the while my answer was commented to death about not being generic. :P

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest changing you configuration properties a bit (getters and setters omitted for brevity):

```
public enum Type {
    BUS, CAR
}

@ConfigurationProperties("rest-config")
public class RestConfig {
    private Map<Type, ConfigType> type = new HashMap<>();

    public static class ConfigType {
        private int tyres;
        private int seats;
        private string color;
        private string url;
    }
}
```

With that you can have the following configuration file:

```
rest-config:
  type:
    bus:
      tyres: 8
      seats: 40
      color: red
      url: www.businfo.com
    car:
      tyres: 4
      seats: 6
      color: blue
      url: www.carinfo.com
```

And finally your helper:

```
@Service
public class RestClientService {

    @Autowired
    private RestConfig config;

    public RestTemplate giveMeRestTemplate(Type type) {
        RestConfig.ConfigType cfg = config.getType().get(type);
        // do what's necessary with cfg
        return restTemplate;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you help with what is going inside the RestConfig map?

Comment: Your properties from `application.yml` file are mapped there by Spring. You can see the example configuration file in the post as well.

Comment: so again here am passing the whole Type enum which contains Bus and Car configs, but why would my rest template need that? if i send it a exact type of Config either Bus or Car.So goal is to avoid writing logic in ur RestClientService where we are writing logic to get type or to know which type of config is that. 'RestConfig.ConfigType cfg = config.getType().get(type);' how to keep this generic so it just give me rest template with whatever property am sending it through params like we pas `context` to methods

Comment: You pass just a Type enum. Retrieval of value from map is barely any logic IMO. In your example CarConfig and BusConfig are separate classes and cannot be both accepted by single method - unless that method accepts simply Object, but that's as far from generic solution as possible. You can try to pass Map<String, Object> if you want arbitrary parameters.

Comment: "am passing the whole Type enum which contains Bus and Car configs" - that's not the case. Type enum doesn't contain anything, it's configuration properties which contain configs for different types.

Comment: sorry, but do you mean CAR and BUS inside enum are not beans? which contains carconfig or bus config?

Comment: In your example CarConfig and BusConfig are separate classes and cannot be both accepted by single method >> agree to this , but just want to make it generic. If we pass just Object is it impossible to be generic?

Comment: config.getType(). is not there , In Map is it by mistake ConfigForType ? should it be ConfigType

Comment: sorry but your solution is not generic, can you explain what is that inside the enum? BUS and CAR are what? i need to pass the BUS config or Car Config which i can pass around and based on that make the template. How in the above way if i call give me rest tempalte will get bus config info or car config so i can prepare different template.

Comment: I find this discussion counter-productive at best. You seem to be talking about generic solution, but you didn't state _what problem_ should be solved at all. How do you expect to use your `BusConfig` or `CarConfig`? How is my solution not generic? In what terms?

Comment: ok, i did not wanted a redesign per say. I could have redesigned if it supported my goal.
Simply creating a enum with BUS and CAR won't make it generic. The only method which need to be generically accepting different type of object either through inheritance or not is  `giveMeRestTemplate(Type type) {` in Rest template i dont know the type it should come as params to this method 'RestConfig.ConfigType cfg = config.getType().get(type);' i cant do this because am supposed to send the type to giveMeRestTemplate. Thanks for your help.